# jQuery: Enumerate elements after deletion

Tags: jquery, each

Here is simplified version of my page:

#### html

```
<div id="id-0" class="item">x</div>
<div id="id-1" class="item">x</div>
<div id="id-2" class="item">x</div>
```

#### script

```
$('.item').click(function() {
    $(this).remove();
    $('.item').each(function(index) {
        $(this).attr('id', 'new_id-' + index);
    }
});
```

When I click on `id=1` element, it's deleted, and here what I see in firebug:

```
<div id="new_id-0" class="item">x</div>
<div id="new_id-2" class="item">x</div>
```

But I need numbers in sequence. Why it counts deleted item and how can I fix this?

Comment: I fixed your jQuery and it worked fine...check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TXvT7/)

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe the problem was the typo :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you have an error in your syntax. You're not closing the parenthesis for `jQuery(".item").each();`

```
$('.item').click(function() {
    $(this).remove();
    $('.item').each(function(index) {
        $(this).attr('id', 'new_id-' + index);
    });
});
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Dpzp) - it recounts just fine